# Is head orientation tracking effective on kinect 2?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm interested in using kinect 2 head orientation as an estimate of gaze direction (it's an estimate because it does not include eye tracking). How robust is the head orientation tracking? I'm particularly interested in cases where the person is not facing towards the kinect.

Answer (score 0):

Upper-body joint tracking is the more robust and effetive tracking that Kinect v2 can handle.

I have made a validity test and the upper body reliability is much higher for the upper body than the lower body. When compared with a GT, the Pearson's R for the head was 0.99, with a concordance correlation coefficient of 0.88. Therefore, yeah, it is effective.

Just make sure your head isn't occluded from the sensor.